# Swift 3 run error

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to create a table view the import the .count of my var and I get an error when I run it

```
Error class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
```

my code

```
   import UIKit
var Urter = ["Timian", "Rosmarin", "Random urt", "Random urt", "Random urt", "Random urt"]



class MenuTab1: UITableViewController {



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return Urter.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)


    cell.textLabel?.text = Urter[indexPath.row]
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Not clear what your problem is. Can you specify you problem?

Comment: I think you should declare array 'Urter' inside the table view controller, below class name.

Comment: can you specify what is the error you are getting? Try moving the var inside the class too.

Comment: you should upload the error log, take a screenshot

Comment: The only thing that looks like it could obviously cause an error here is if you neglected to specify the storyboard identifier of `cell` for your prototype cell. Or perhaps your scene is not a `UITableViewController`, but rather a `UIViewController` with a table view. But it could be any of a number of other things, too, and without seeing the full error message that shows up on the console, it's hard to tell.